# What encoding to get Å Ä Ö to work

Tags: windows, character-encoding, utf-8, vb.net

I'm writing a small application in VB.NET that will enable me to
easily create a user "Windows 7 account" with a password, instead of
going through the control panel.
The problem I'm having is that when I create a batch file in VB.NET
using UTF-8 encoding, it doesn't write å ä ö as it's supposed to.
I have tried all encodings I can find, but am unable to get it working.

If anyone has an idea of why I'm getting this, please let me know.

Comment: try posting on stackoverflow.com and show your script.

Comment: @Toby Allen Well it's not really a programming question but a question about encoding text, the same problem occurs when I create a .bat file  the "normal" way.

Comment: Related.
• [What encoding to get Å Ä Ö to work](https://superuser.com/q/675369)
• [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654)
• [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490)
• [chcp 65001 and a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32182619)
• [Making Swedish characters show properly in Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660264)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** I was wrong ;)
`cmd.exe` does accept UTF-8 but you need to be sure to save it **without** the `BOM` at the beginning of the file.

Here is a second test. You can use `chcp 65001` at the beginning of your batch-file.

[image]

---

A batch file **can not** be of type UTF-8. It needs to be ASCII. `Cmd.exe` just doesn't accept another format. I did a small test and you can use your characters but it needs some work.

Make a file `test.bat` with `echo Å Ä Ö`. Save it with format `ANSI/ASCII`. Open a `cmd.exe` and make sure your `cmd.exe` uses `Lucida Console` (to display the Unicode characters).

When you type the file it will show characters as the old DOS-characters. You can see a translation chart [here](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-pc.htm).

When you switch to a "Windows Ansi"-[code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) (i.e. West European Latin) with `chcp 1252` the characters are displayed correctly. If they also get transferred to their respective utilities depends on that utility.

But why are you creating a batch-file for this? Can't you just code it in VB.net?

[image: cmd.exe]

---

## Edit 2#:

This is how you set `Lucida Console` in `cmd.exe`:

[image: Lucida Console]

---

The `BOM` are 3 characters at the beginning of a UTF-8 file. (`\xEF\xBB\xBF`).
In VB.net you would create a file **without** a `BOM` like this:

```
Dim utf8WithoutBom As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False)
                                                  '^^^^^'
Using sink As New StreamWriter("Foobar.txt", False, utf8WithoutBom)
    sink.WriteLine("...")
End Using
```

Comment: Hi and thanx for the answer. In my vb.net application I'm trying to create a .bat file with the commands: 
net user "username"
net localgroup administratörer "type" /add
The reason i have to use the Swedish word adminstratörer instead of administator is beause localgroup won't take the English translation as a group.

Comment: Just thought going through a .bat-file was a bit much when you could do this straight from VB.net. Like [here](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/371016-create-windows-user-account). Lots of examples in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+add+user+windows) too. So no need to create a .bat as middle-man. And with those examples you could feed the Unicode-name directly to the Windows-function. (Unless you need to run the .bat at a different time separate from your VB.net app for some reason?)

Comment: Well I have been looking for a way to do this in VB.net on Google for days, though I haven't found any way do do it. I already tried the example you linked and it didn't seem to work. 

How do I make sure that the .bat file doesn't use BOM? 
Also what is Lucida Console? The only info I could find about it is that it's a font.

When I try the exact thing you did in the second example/image I get this http://i.imgur.com/6sh20j0.jpg

Comment: I added to my answer to include `Lucida Console` and file-creation without `BOM` (Edit #2, at the bottom). But does creating this user via `net user` work on the command-prompt? And what does not work if you create it via VB.net? For this we would need some example-code (or a separate question) because this should work. (BTW you linked my image, not yours, i think, in your comment)

Comment: So I changed it to Lucia Console and not it seems to work. Though I need the script to run on other machines too and the Lucia console is only saved on the machine i changed it on right?  I made a separate question for how to do this in VB.NET instead here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974473/making-a-windows-user-using-vb-net
P.S Yes creating a user in command-prompt does work and yes I accidentally linked the wrong image :P

Comment: Actually for the batch file the font wouldn't be that important (it's only for display on screen). The .bat should just run fine on the other machines **without** setting the `cmd.exe` to `Lucida Console`. (You would need the chcp 65001 though). Does your .bat do the correct job now or do you still have troubles with it?

Comment: Yeah, I know that the font doesn't affect if the command works or not. Yes as far as I can tell it's working right now. I'll implement it into my application, I'll post again if I get any more problems! Thanx man :D

Comment: Tested some more now by creating a .bat file using VB.NET Here is the code
 My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(CurDir() + "\adduser.bat", "chcp 65001" + Environment.NewLine + "net user " + UserBox.Text + " " + PaswordBox.Text + "/add" + Environment.NewLine + "net localgroup " + UserType + " " + UserBox.Text + " " + "/add " + Environment.NewLine + "pause", False, utf8WithoutBom)

Though the CMD window opens for a split second, which would indicate that it cannot read the text.

Comment: Do a `type adduser.bat` on the `cmd.exe`. What do you get? Are there unreadable characters on the first line? And you didn't use `StreamWriter` but `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText`. Maybe `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText` doesn't do the non-BOM thing. so rewrite it to use `StreamWriter` like in my example.

Comment: You could also try `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(CurDir() + "\adduser.bat", Text, False, Encoding.ASCII)`. See [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1169840.aspx?Three+hex+characters+being+saved+at+beginning+of+text+file+with+WriteAllText). Not sure if it keeps the utf-8 characters but you can try ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11491/discussion-between-kagstrom2100-and-rik)

Comment: NB: doing `chcp 65001` followed by `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 | find " = "` will cause your computer to hang; I think the character set affects `find` (as the ping without this filter works perfectly)

Comment: @JohnLBevan Yeah, you're right. Apparently `find` doesn't handle UTF-8 input not too well. But you can use `findstr`. Like this: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 | findstr /C:" = "`

Comment: The link http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-pc.htm has since become broken.
Alas, I was not able to find a good replacement. :-(

Comment: @Henke That's what the Internet Archive project is for :) (WaybackMachine) See https://web.archive.org/web/20160126172420/http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-pc.htm

Answer (score 4):

The thing that fixed this for me was to save the file as UTF-8 without BOM and using this code

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
net user Linus /add
net localgroup Administratörer Test/add
```

The thing I didn't use before was **@echo off** so that and using chcp 65001 is what fixed it! Thanx too Rik for all the help :)

Comment: +1 for 65001 :)